# jquery fadeIn effect with <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding rows dynamically to a table based on selection yet I would like to add fadeIn effect.
I am posting the part in which I add the rows to table.
Any help will be appreciated. 
(I am trying to use the fadeIn effect while adding newRow to table and removing tblGraphPattern content afterwards). I want to have the effect in the lines

$("table.selectPattern").append(newRow);

$("#tblGraphPattern tr").remove();

```
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
                    newRow.attr("align","center");
                    newRow.css("outline", "thin solid");
                    for(var i = 1; i<counter;++i)
                    {

                        if($("#divSubject"+i+"").length>0)
                        {       
                        var cols = "";          
                        subjectText=$("#divSubject"+i+"").html();
                        if(subjectText=="Any")
                            {subjectVal = "?s"+selectCounter;}
                        else{subjectVal=$("#txtGraphSubject"+i+"").val();}

                        predicateText=$("#divPredicate"+i+"").html();
                        if(predicateText=="Any")
                            {predicateVal = "?p"+selectCounter;}
                        else{predicateVal=$("#txtGraphPredicate"+i+"").val();}
                        objectText=$("#divObject"+i+"").html();
                        if(objectText=="Any"){objectVal="?o"+selectCounter;}
                        else{
                            objectVal=$("#txtGraphObject"+i+"").val();
                        }           

                        cols += '<tr><td align="right"><div id="divSelectSubject'+num+'">'+subjectText+'</div><input type="text" value="'+subjectVal+'" name="txtSelectSubject'
                                + num + '" id="txtSelectSubject'    + num + '"/></td>';
                        cols +=  '<td align="center"><div id="divSelectPredicate'+num+'">'+predicateText+'</div><input type="text" value="'+predicateVal+
                        '" name="txtSelectPredicate' + num + '" id="txtSelectPredicate' + num + '"/></td>';
                        cols +=  '<td align="left"><div id="divSelectObject'+num+'">'+objectText+'</div><input type="text" value="'+objectVal+
                        '" name="txtSelectObject' + num + '" id="txtSelectObject'   + num + '"/></td></tr>';

                        newRow.append(cols);
                        }
                        num++;
                    }
                    selectCounter++;
                    newRow.append('<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel"  value="Delete"></td>');

                    $("table.selectPattern").append(newRow);
                    $("#tblGraphPattern tr").remove();
```

Comment: `was not helpful` is not much of an explanation ...did you hide the row before trying to fadeIn() ? Can't fade something in that's already visible. Please provide demo that replicates your problem

Comment: $("table.selectPattern").append(newRow);
                    $("#tblGraphPattern tr").remove();
these two lines are where I add the newRow and remove the content of the other table. This is where I am trying to use the fade effects. I posted the rest of the code to make sure there's nothing wrong while forming the newRow that might cause the problem.

Comment: You have not stated what the problem really is. There is nothing showing you hiding the row like `row.hide().fadeIn("slow");`

Comment: yes I am asking how to add it, I removed what I wrote to avoid confusion. OK I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `newRow` hidden by setting `display:none;` before appending it to `table.selectPattern` and then fadeIn after appending is done.

```
var newRow = $('<tr style="display:none;"></tr>');
// your remaining code
$("table.selectPattern").append(newRow);
$("#tblGraphPattern tr").remove();
newRow.fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: didn't work, I managed to remove with fadeOut by
$("#tblGraphPattern tr").fadeOut(300, function(){ 
     $("#tblGraphPattern tr").remove(); 
              });
but with your code the newRow is not visible at all

Comment: when you say it didn't work, is it showing any error in console ?

Comment: Haha.. good to know, I was wondering if there's a mistake in my code :)